# Cropping openstreemap tiles to desired bounding box

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, interpolation, rendering, clip

Given the solution for downloading a cluster of tiles in

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476117/easy-openstreetmap-tile-displaying-for-python

and

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Python

what is a good way of EXACTLY cropping the resulting image to the DESIRED bounding box using Python?

Is interpolation necessary?

Note that when downloading OSM tiles you usually get returned a bounding box that is larger or equal the desired one due to the discreet nature of the tiles.